# LeafXnet как хранить Cookie

Tags: c#, xnet

вопрос в том как при получении Cookie GET запросом с сайта,  с разных ссылок хранить их в одной переменной. На картинке показан пример куков которые мне нужны,  но они почти все с разных ссылок, как правильно хранить их и устанавливать по ссылкам?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
private void Get_Cookie()
{
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en; rv:1.8.1.4pre) Gecko/20070417 Camino/1.1b+";
    HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru");
    Cookie = response.Cookies.GetCookieHeader("https://account.mail.ru/signup?from=main&rf=auth.mail.ru");
}
private void Get_Cookie_p()
{
    Get_Cookie();
    var request = new HttpRequest();
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en; rv:1.8.1.4pre) Gecko/20070417 Camino/1.1b+";
    HttpResponse response = request.Get("https://rs.mail.ru/d26047874.gif?sz=49&rnd=135199482&ts=1588341126&sz=49");
    request.Cookies = response.Cookies;
    Cookie = response.Cookies.GetCookieHeader("https://rs.mail.ru/d26047874.gif?sz=49&rnd=135199482&ts=1588341126&sz=49");
}
```

Comment: Можно каждую куку(не все куки) записывать в List, потом из него брать все значения и подставлять для request.Cookies, при каждой следующей итерации если нужно, очищать. Возможно поможет [CookieContainer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.cookiecontainer?view=netcore-3.1) с статической переменной

Comment: Для нашёл такой хитрый выход. Мне нужно с двух ссылок сложить куки в одну переменную, таким интересным способом всё работает.                                                                                        
Cookie += "; " + response.Cookies.GetCookieHeader("https://rssz=49");